# Passing empty model to vue type casting error

Tags: php, laravel

I have empty object ($attributes array is empty) and i pass it to component in blade like:

```
<example :box="{{ $box }}" > </example>
```

My props in component are:

```
box: {
    type: Object,
    required: true  
},
```

I got an error *Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "box". Expected Object, got Array*.

But if I do e.g. `$box->id = null` in Controller everything is OK. Is there another way to solve this, not adding extra code?

**EDIT:**
controllers action has:

```
return view( 'my_view' )->with('box', new Box());
```

In html output I get `:box="[]"`. And if I set `$box->id = null` output is like `:box="{&quot;id&quot;:null}"`

Comment: What does the rendered HTML source look like (view source in your browser)

Comment: You don't have a closing quote for the `:box` attribute value, does adding it change anything? Also, please include the controller; `$box` might actually be an array (e.g. using `get()` instead of `first()` or similar)

Comment: @Phil I edited post

Comment: That seems odd. Can you share the `Box` class definition?

Answer (score 0):

Blade template:

```
 <example :box="{{ json_encode($box) }}" > </example>
```

component vue:

```
 <template>
   <div>
        {{box}}
   </div>
 </template>
 <scipt>
     export default{
        props['box']
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can define default value of props.

Please check [Vue.js Document: Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation).

Comment: `$box` is passed always, default value will never be used, I tried